# query in SQL to get the months b/w the dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the following data.

```
id  Date of Issue  Date of Travel       
---------------------------------

1   10-april-2011  10-may-2011    
2   25-april-2011  22-may-2011
```

How can I display the number of months between the `Date of Issue` and `Date of Travel` in SQL (I am using an MS Access database)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question, you need to use the DateDiff function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ("m", [id Date of Issue], [Date of Travel]) FROM ...
```

Comment: ok, that was nicer then mine, need to learn all thus date funktions someday :-)

Answer (score 0):

To count the months between the dates:

```
SELECT MONTH('Date of Travel')-MONTH('Date of Issue')+12*(YEAR('Date of Travel')-YEAR('Date of Issue'))
```